# Same global accessed via module or folder module have inconsistent values

Tags: python, module, scope, global

I'm having trouble understanding the scope of global variables in python.
Maybe it's something wrong with the module or something wrong the way I'm using the global variable.

I have a global variable, and I can use it via full namespace folder/module or only folder.  But I don't have the expected value if I use it with only the folder.

In this short file I will explain the problem I'm having:

```
import folder

print("Both values must be zero")
print('folder.value_count')
print(folder.value_count)
print('folder.utils.value_count')
print(folder.utils.value_count)

folder.increment_count()

print("Both values must be one")
print('folder.value_count')
print(folder.value_count)
print('folder.utils.value_count')
print(folder.utils.value_count)

print("Both values must be one")
print('folder.get_value_count()')
print(folder.get_value_count())
print('folder.utils.get_value_count()')
print(folder.utils.get_value_count())
```

The results shown in the console:

```
Both values must be zero
folder.value_count
0
folder.utils.value_count
0
Both values must be one
folder.value_count
0
folder.utils.value_count
1
Both values must be one
folder.get_value_count()
1
folder.utils.get_value_count()
1
```

Content of file folder\__init__.py:

```
__version__ = '0.0.0'

from . import utils
from .utils import *
```

Content of file folder\utils.py

```
value_count = 0

def increment_count():
    global value_count
    value_count += 1

def get_value_count():
    global value_count
    return value_count
```

Then I'm not sure why if the use of folder.value_count is not the same value of folder.utils.value_count, but If I use the function folder.get_value_count() is the same value of folder.utils.get_value_count().

Thanks in advance

Comment: ``folder.value_count`` and ``folder.utils.value_count`` are not the same global. ``get_value_count`` and ``increment_count`` will always use the same global – the one next to which they were defined – regardless where they are called from.

Comment: It means with only one declaration value_count = 0 in python, it can be interpreted in several scopes at the same time?

Comment: It means that `from .utils import *` creates a new global variable.